# Install Android USB Driver when device is not shown in device manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers, android, nexus-5

the title is quite explicit : 
I'm trying to install google's driver for my android device in order to use it for development ( I need it to be seen by 'adb devices' )

I've got a Nexus 5 and windows 7 x64

Everywhere I can read :

> plug your device, go to device manager, right click on Android device,
>   update driver and choose from disk to install google's usb-driver from the extra folder of
>   android sdk

But when I plug my nexus 5 to my pc, nothing happen at all :(
I've try several usb ports, several usb conection modes (on the phone : MTP, PTP) with usb debug enabled/disabled.  there is nothing I can do.

I've also try another device : the sony xperia Z1. this one is shown as "**Unknown Device**" and if I try to install google's driver, it says

> The driver for this hardware is up to date : "Unknown device"

I've got no lead so any advice is welcome.

EDIT : 
[this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/nexus-5-seen-pc-t2537420) from xda-developpers says "uninstall all drivers" then plug the android device...

Does anyone know how to uninstall a driver that is not showing up in wondows 7 ?

Comment: Maybe your phone's USB port or cable is just broken?

Comment: I've got the phone battery charging so I thought it was working fine but indeed, there is no "usb mode alert", no notification about the usb connection as it should be :/  I'll try another usb cable and let you know if it helps

Comment: AFAIK, USB 2.0 connections use two pairs of wires – one for power, one for data; I've heard of USB "charge only" cables that only have one pair and cannot carry data. (Just one more thing that makes me go _"why would you sell junk like that?"_ but oh well.)

Answer (score 3):

Ok  thanks a lot to Mr grawity :)

I've manage to see the nexus 5 appear in windows 7 device manager by **using another usb cable**.

As you said Why the hell would someone sell usb cable with "Charge only" capability :(
but we should be aware : that exists.

Comment: Your cable might have become broken.  I just had this same issue with a cable that I knew was good in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue with my Sony Xperia Z1. I have managed this by "Installing the Device Software" in my PC